# Nextjs app loads plain html text instead of rendering the html

Tags: next.js

Nextjs app loads plain html text instead of rendering the html

App was working fine, but all of a sudden on browser refresh, I see only plain html text. Checked the git commits and found that nothing has changed

What could be the issue?

[image]

Tried restarting the server, deleting the cache in browser and deleting the `.next` folder as well

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the below headers from `next.config.js` worked. I am not sure why this caused an issue

```
async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        headers: [
          { key: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/json' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', value: 'true' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: 'http://localhost:4200' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', value: 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', value: 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version' },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
```

Comment: That content-type will force the app to try to display the content as if it were of the type 'application/json', hence why it displays as text.